# Criteria Builder JOIN on unreferenced table

Tags: java, jpa, join

Is it possible to perform a join with `CriteriaBuilder` on a table that is not referenced by the selected entity? Since `CriteriaBuilder.join()` expects as parameter the attribute name, it seems like it won't work.

To be a bit clearer, the original query looks like this:
`select Vehicle v left join VehicleStatus vs on v.id = vs.vehicleId`...

`Vehicle` does not define a relationship to `VehicleStatus`. And changes to the database are currently undesired though possible if needed.

Currently the code I have

```
final Join<Vehicle, VehicleStatus> vs = vehicle.join("vs", JoinType.LEFT);
vs.on(cb.equal(vs.get("vehicleId"), vehicle.get("id")));
```

fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [vs] on this ManagedType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need a mapped association to create a join clause with the `CriteriaBuilder`.

With Hibernate, you can [join 2 unassociated entities](https://thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) in a JPQL query. The syntax is almost identical to SQL. But it's a Hibernate-specific feature and not part of the JPA standard.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if it is different if the joined table is actually a view? In that case I can't have it referenced by the entity.